# Is it possible to change the order of summation for $\sum_{i=0}^{2} \sum_{j=i}^{3} (i+j)^3?$

Tags: calculus, summation

Is it possible to change the order of summation for the following expression: $$\sum_{i=0}^{2} \sum_{j=i}^{3} (i+j)^3?$$

If so, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just write out all sumands?

Answer (score 2):

We can change the order of summation if the upper limit of both sums is $3$. So, we can write
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{2}\sum_{j=i}^3(i+j)^3}
&=\sum_{i=0}^3\sum_{j=i}^3(i+j)^3-\sum_{j=3}^3(3+j)^3\\
&=\sum_{0\leq i\leq j\leq 3}(i+j)^3-6^3\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^3\sum_{i=0}^j(i+j)^3-6^3}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to compute
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m A_{ij}.
$$

The terms to be added can be put in a table, where $i$ corresponds to the number of the line
$$
\begin{align*}
A_{00}+A_{01}+A_{13} + \cdots + A_{0m}+\\
A_{10}+A_{11}+A_{12} + \cdots + A_{1m}+\\
\vdots\\
A_{n0}+A_{n1}+A_{n2} + \cdots + A_{nm}\\
\end{align*}
$$

How would you write the (equivalent) sum that corresponds to adding "column" by "column"?

---

**Edit**: In the specific case mentioned in the OP, the sum in $j$ only starts at $i$, meaning that we would have $A_{ij} = 0$ for $j<i$:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
A_{00} &+ A_{01} &+ A_{02} &+ A_{03}\\
0 &+ A_{11} &+ A_{12} &+ A_{13}\\
0 &+ 0 &+ A_{22} &+ A_{23}
\end{array}
$$

So, adding column by column, you get
$$
\sum_{i=0}^2 \sum_{j=i}^3 A_{ij} = \sum_{j=0}^3 \sum_{i=0}^{\min\{j,2\}} A_{ij}
$$

Comment: OP's j starts at i. This would be a triangular thing

Comment: @DavidP It could be triangular, yes, but this is also ok because we can set $A_{ij} = 0$ for $j < i$.

Comment: @PierreCarre My apologies, I fail to understand how to apply this technique to my case.

Comment: @PierreCarre The best I was able to come up with is $\sum_{j=0}^{3} \sum_{i=0}^{j}(i+j)^{3} $, however this is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A good general way to manipulate indices of multiple sums is to look at them as a system of inequalities.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^2 \sum_{j=i}^3 \cdots $$

represents the integer solutions to

$$ \begin{align*} i &\geq 0 \\ i &\leq 2 \\ j &\geq i \\ j &\leq 3 \end{align*} $$

For $j$ on the outside sum, the absolute smallest $j$ can be is $0$, and the absolute largest $j$ can be is $3$. To put the $i$ variable on the inside sum, we have $0\leq i$, $i \leq 2$, and $i \leq j$. We can combine the two upper bounds with a $\min$ function:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^2 \sum_{j=i}^3 f(i,j) = \sum_{j=0}^3 \sum_{i=0}^{\min(j,2)} f(i,j) $$

Or, we can split the sum into the parts where each upper limit applies, depending whether $j<2$ or $j\geq 2$. ($j \leq 2$ and $j>2$ would also work.)

$$ \sum_{i=0}^2 \sum_{j=i}^3 f(i,j) = \sum_{j=0}^1 \sum_{i=0}^j f(i,j) + \sum_{j=2}^3 \sum_{i=0}^2 f(i,j) $$

$j \leq 2$ and $j>2$ also works, and in this case $j>2$ implies $j=3$:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^2 \sum_{j=i}^3 f(i,j) = \sum_{j=0}^2 \sum_{i=0}^j f(i,j) + \sum_{i=0}^2 f(i,3) $$